# How to remove padding in HorizontalGridView on Leanback

Tags: android, television, leanback

I'm trying to remove the inner padding of the `Presenter`'s container on leanback which is `HorizontalGridView` but I still can't figure it out.

I've tried to apply directly the needed padding (0dp) by getting the reference of the HorizontalGridView in the `onCreateViewHolder()`, at start I can see that the padding is gone but once I scroll down and then back to the row, it is reset to it's initial state.
I also tried to override the style's `@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.HorizontalGridView` `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` but to no avail.
I've tried to switch from a `Presenter` to a `RowPresenter` and it changed nothing.

[image: Please find attached what I need to remove as padding.]

Thank you for taking the time to read my question :)

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I implemented a `RowPresenter()` instead of `Presenter()`, removed it's header and It worked !